# Extract data with XSLT from two combined XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a representation of two DB tables in XML.

record.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>        
            <records>
            <record>
             <ID>20345</ID>
             <name>John Doe</name>
             <address>23 Green Hill, NY</address>
            </record>
            ...
            <record>
             <ID>67357</ID>
             <name>Simon Lee</name>
             <address>23 South Oates Street, Dothan</address>
            </record>
            </records>
```

and

work.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?>
    
        <employees>
        <employee>
        <ID>20345</ID>
        <position>General Manager</position>
        <level>0</level>
        </employee>
        ...
        <employee>
        <ID>67357</ID>
        <position>Senior Officer</position>
        <level>1</level>
        </employee>
        </employees>
```

My XSLT file transform.xsl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"         
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output media-type="xml" indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="/records/record">   
            <record>            
                <ID><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></ID>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
                <address><xsl:value-of select="address"/></address>
                <position><xsl:value-of select="document(work.xml)/employees/employee/position"/></position>
                <level><xsl:value-of select="document(work.xml)/employees/employee/level"/></level>     
            </record>       
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to merge the data for each employee based on ID in the form:

```
ID> 20345
name> John Doe 
address> 23 Green Hill, NY
position> General Manager
level> 0
...
ID> 67357
name> Simon Lee
address> 23 South Oates Street, Dothan
position> Senior Officer
level> 1
```

I tried to use a template with parameters $position and $level but I am not sure what XQuery to use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
<xsl:output media-type="xml" indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:param name="work" select="work.xml" />
<xsl:param name="merged" select="document($work)" />
<xsl:variable name="ID" select="$merged/employees/employee/ID" />
<xsl:variable name="position" select="$merged/employees/employee/position" />
<xsl:variable name="level" select="$merged/employees/employee/level" />


<xsl:key name="IDkey" match="$ID" use="ID"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/records/record"/>
  <xsl:template match="employees/employee">
  <xsl:value-of select="key('IDkey',document(work.xml)/employees/employee/ID])"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/records/record">   
        <record>            
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></ID>
            <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
            <address><xsl:value-of select="address"/></address> 
            <position><xsl:value-of select="position"/></position>
            <level><xsl:value-of select="level"/></level>               
        </record>       
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would really appreciate some help..

Comment: Use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#key) to resolve cross-references.

Comment: Per your script, are you asking an XSLT 3.0 question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest key based cross-reference would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="work">
<employees>
        <employee>
        <ID>20345</ID>
        <position>General Manager</position>
        <level>0</level>
        </employee>
        ...
        <employee>
        <ID>67357</ID>
        <position>Senior Officer</position>
        <level>1</level>
        </employee>
        </employees>      
  </xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:key name="id" match="employee" use="ID"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="record[key('id', ID, $work)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('id', ID, $work)!(position, level)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other data is inline above (and online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nb9PtEb) for compactness and self-containedness of the example but of course using `<xsl:param name="work" select="doc('work.xml')"/>` would work the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the last part of the code the XPath function of the template "node(), key('id', ID, $work)!(position, level)" was called with the wrong number of arguments.

Comment: @user11007053, the only XPath function call in that cited snippet is `key('id', ID, $work)` and in XSLT 2 and 3 the `key` function allows three arguments and the third argument is essential to simplify the use of keys with two documents you want to merge.

Comment: When I run the code within IE I get error "XSLT8690: XSLT processing failed." Firefox gives me error "Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath function was called with the wrong number of arguments."  Do I have to include any other stylesheet relative to Saxon preocessor?

Comment: The native XSLT support in browsers is XSLT 1 only, I am not sure how you want to run your XSLT, your own code says version 3.0 so my answer assumes that version.

Comment: To use XSLT 3 in the browser, you would need to use Saxon JS 2 from Saxonica.