# How to apply multiple templates from comibed XML files with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created this [fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4va) for testing

My XML is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<t:object xmlns:t="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/types-3"
          xmlns="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
          xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
          xmlns:apti="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/api-types-3">
    

   <apti:object oid="2">      
      <name></name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="1"/>      
   </apti:object>

   <apti:object oid="4">  
      <name>50001007</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="3"/>
   </apti:object>

   <apti:object oid="5">    
      <name>50001012</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="4"/>      
   </apti:object>

   <apti:object oid="6">      
      <name>50001806</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="5"/>
   </apti:object>

   <apti:object oid="3">      
      <name>50001802</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="2"/>      
   </apti:object>
      
   <apti:object oid="7">  
      <name>50001742</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="6"/>
   </apti:object>

   <apti:object oid="1">      
    <name>50001282</name>
      <parentOrgRef oid="0"/>      
   </apti:object>
</t:object>
```

My XSL is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
          xmlns:t="http://prism.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/types-3"
          xmlns="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
          xmlns:c="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"
          xmlns:apti="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/api-types-3">

<xsl:output media-type="xml" indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="config">
<units>
    
  <unit>
    <name></name>
    <description>ΔΙΟΙΚΗΤΙΚΟ ΣΥΜΒΟΥΛΙΟ</description>
    <level>0</level>
    <company>AtGroup</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001007</name>
    <description>Διευθύνων Σύμβουλος</description>
    <level>0</level>
    <company>CLR</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001012</name>
    <description>Γραφείο Διευθύνοντος Συμβούλου</description>
    <level>1</level>
    <company>ERT</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001806</name>
    <description>Μονάδα Νομικής Υποστήριξης Οργάνωσης &amp; Διαχειριστικής Λειτουργίας των Εταιρειών</description>
    <level>2</level>
    <company>ERT</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001802</name>
    <description>Μονάδα Υποστήριξης Δ.Σ. &amp; Εταιρικής Διακυβέρνησης</description>
    <level>1</level>
    <company>GDR</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001742</name>
    <description>Διευθύνση Εσωτερικού Ελέγχου</description>
    <level>1</level>
    <company>TCW</company>
  </unit>
  
  <unit>
    <name>50001282</name>
    <description>Διεύθυνση Ανθρώπινου Δυναμικού</description>
    <level>1</level>
    <company>ABC</company>
  </unit>
  
</units>
</xsl:param>


<xsl:key name="id" match="unit" use="name"/>
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:template match="apti:object[key('id', name, $config)]">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), key('id', name, $config)!(description, level)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="apti:object">   
    <Record>
        <parent_description><xsl:value-of select="c:parentOrgRef/@oid"/></parent_description>
         <parent_name></parent_name>
        <level></level>             
        <company></company>
    </Record>       
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to produce a new XML in the form

```
    <parent_description></parent_description>
     <parent_name></parent_name>
    <level></level>             
    <company></company>
```

I am trying to make a key to get for each **apti:object** node the name of the parent node based on the **parentOrgRef**
I cannot get the values of level and company although my key **'id'** works.
I have combined two XML files.
I would really appreciate some help..

Comment: Sounds like a task for a key. Consider to provide minimal but complete samples of input and wanted output inside your question as code samples, without the overhead of a full sample with lots of data irrelevant to the question in a linked fiddle.

Comment: Hello Martin. Yes I understood the keys from your last example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539013/extract-data-with-xslt-from-two-combined-xml-files)    but I am not sure how to "link" the templates..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to declare `xpath-default-namespace="http://midpoint.evolveum.com/xml/ns/public/common/common-3"` in your XSLT.

And then write only one template matching

```
<xsl:template match="apti:object">   
    <Record>
        <parent_description><xsl:value-of select="c:parentOrgRef/@oid"/></parent_description>
         <xsl:copy-of select="key('id', name, $config)!(description, level, company)"/>
    </Record>       
</xsl:template>
```